# Are sqlalchemy engine objects disposed automatically?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I have been searching a lot around sqlalchemy connections and engine configuration after I got one of the error:

> psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL:  remaining connection slots are
>   reserved for non-replication superuser connections

I know it is related is `pool_size` and have increased it for the application to work properly. I was wondering why engine object is not disposed of by the garbage collector automatically. Do we always need to call `engine.dispose()` each time?

Also, continuing with the previous argument does `create_engine()` will always create a new object or it can return an existing object and if it can return an existing object what is the deciding criteria (like e.g timeouts etc.) of the engine object to return to the pool again.

Just shout if you need any more information from me.

Comment: Thanks @IljaEverilä  my first question is does it get gc'd automatically? mcve would be just creating a new engine object with postgres connection string. do you need that keeping all the arguments default meaning pool_size and pool class everything and yes I have many scripts/processes running simultaneously if that helps

Comment: If you have many scripts, or in other words processes, running in parallel, they naturally keep a connection pool of their own each. If they are somewhat long lived, they'll hold on to connections they've reserved in their pools, so you just might run out. Either raise your server's `max_connections`, or use an external connection pool such as PgBouncer (and disable pooling in the Python processes).

Comment: max_connection would not solve the issue as it is defined as 100 max_connections in the configs and I don't have those many processes running in parallel.

Comment: How many do you have? How many connections do they use on average? You mentioned using default settings, so it's anywhere between 0 and 10, where 5 is the default amount kept in the pool. With that in mind approx. 20 processes could very well use up your available connections.

Comment: Pool size will not matter when created inside each process right? max_connections do matter I think.

Comment: It will matter if each process hogs a pool full of connections and holds on to them (mid to long lived processes). This question would still benefit from a [mcve].